# Infopath Form and SharePoint lists

Tags: infopath

Ive spent just about all of my day doing what should be simple i think. I have a drop down list (list1) in an infopath 2010 form that pulls from a SharePoint list. How do I filter another SharePoint list based on the currently selected item (from list1).

To be honest I cant even set a textbox to the current value of list1. I understand how to filter and add rules to infopath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use filters. It isn't difficult to do, it just requires a lot of steps. Here are a couple examples:

http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/03/dynamically-filter-a-drop-down-on-your-sharepoint-list-by-another-user-selected-value/

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/filter-the-data-that-is-displayed-in-a-control-HA010024281.aspx

Comment: Finally got it. The problem was, I was query a SharePoint list without using a field in my workflow. I guess it wasnt storing the value anywhere. This meant I wasnt able to use it as a filter.